# Mysql hierarchical query is ignoring duplicate rows (but it shouldn't!)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to put a pedigree together from a table that holds the dogs ID, Name, Sire_ID, Dam_ID. All the dogs are in this one table. I found a nice looking function at sitepoint, but it has a problem, a dog can have the same great grandparent due to linebreeding. If that happens, this function does not work due to this:

```
$sql  = "SELECT name, sire_id, dam_id FROM dogs WHERE id IN($idsx)";
```

$idsx might look like this: (25, 65, 42, 36, 99, 29, 72, 25). Since ID #25 is in there twice, it gets ignored the second time and my pedigree breaks. Is there anyway to make it always return all rows?

Here is the full function:

```
    function query_ancestors($ids,$generation){
    // Make sure we have some doggies to look up
    $results = array();
    if (count($ids) < 1) return $results; // No more ancestors
    // For storing parent ids
    $parentIds = array();
    // Query all of the current generation
    $idsx = implode(',',$ids); // Makes comma delimited string
    $sql  = "SELECT name, sire_id, dam_id FROM dogs WHERE id IN($idsx)";
    $rows = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)){
        // Add to results
        $row['generation'] = $generation;
        $results[] = $row;
        // Find the parents
        if ($row['sire_id']) $parentIds[] = $row['sire_id'];
        if ($row['dam_id'])  $parentIds[] = $row['dam_id'];
    }
    // repeat for all the parent dogs
    $generation++;
    $resultsx = query_ancestors($parentIds,$generation);
    return array_merge($results,$resultsx);
}
```

Call function/output results:

```
$generation = 0;
$ids = array(8); // id of the the dog to start with
$results = query_ancestors($ids,$generation);
foreach($results as $result){
    echo "{$result['generation']} {$result['id']} {$result['name']} <br>\n";
}
```

Updated function:

```
function query_ancestors($ids,$generation){
    // Make sure we have some doggies to look up
    $results = array();
    if (count($ids) < 1) return $results; // No more ancestors
    // For storing parent ids
    $parentIds = array();
    // Query all of the current generation
    $current_gen_ids = implode(',',$ids); // Makes comma delimited string
    $sql  = "SELECT dog_name, dog_sire_id, dog_dam_id FROM dogs JOIN (UNION ALL SELECT $current_gen_ids AS dog_id) AS idsx ON idsx.dog_id = dogs.id";
    $rows = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)){
        // Add to results
        $row['generation'] = $generation;
        $results[] = $row;
        // Find the parents
        if ($row['dog_sire_id']) $parentIds[] = $row['dog_sire_id'];
        if ($row['dog_dam_id'])  $parentIds[] = $row['dog_dam_id'];
    }
    // And here is the trick, repeat for all the parent dogs
    $generation++;
    $resultsx = query_ancestors($parentIds,$generation);
    return array_merge($results,$resultsx);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this change:

```
// Query all of the current generation
// Makes a table to be used for JOIN
$idsx = 'SELECT ' . implode(' AS id UNION ALL SELECT ', $ids ) . ' AS id' ;

$sql  = "SELECT dog_name, dog_sire_id, dog_dam_id FROM dogs JOIN (" 
      . $idsx . ") AS idsx ON idsx.id = dogs.id ";
```

Comment: When I tried this I got a "implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed". I'm not sure what's happening, so I tried breaking things down a little more. Now I have invalid sql (You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION ALL SELECT 367, 391 AS dog_id) AS idsx ON idsx.dog_id = dogs.id
LIMIT 0, ' at line 1). Also, I updated my column names with a "dog_" prefix, sorry for any confusion. I edited the original post with the new code.

Comment: @Brandon: My wrong. Try now. My code tries to wite the query as: `... FROM dogs JOIN (SELECT 25 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 73 AS id ... UNION ALL SELECT 25 AS id) AS idsx ON idsx.id = dogs.id` The `UNION ALL` will keep (and join) duplicate ids.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're doing! Works great. It's fast too. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if 25 is in that array once, twice, or twenty times. `IN()` only needs to know that it is in there at all.

You might want to look at the [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function instead

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql  = "SELECT name, sire_id, dam_id FROM dogs WHERE id IN($idsx)";
$rows = mysql_query($sql);
$intermediate = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)){
    // Add to results
    $row['generation'] = $generation;
    // Find the parents
    $intermediate[$row['id']] = $row;
}
foreach($ids as $id){
    if ($intermediate[$id]['sire_id']) $parentIds[] = $intermediate[$id]['sire_id'];
    if ($intermediate[$id]['dam_id'])  $parentIds[] = $intermediate[$id]['dam_id'];    
    $results[] = $intermediate[$id];
}
```